# Print only part of values or to a specific character

Tags: php, mysql

I have in MySQL table column "class"
and in items is :

- DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)
- DCK1 (koerakross, lapsed 6-9)
- DBW (jalgrattavedu, naised al.16 a.)
- DR4 (3-4 koera käruvedu, al.16 a.)
- DR6 (4-6 koera käruvedu al. 16 a.)
- DCK2 (koerakross, lapsed10-13 a.) 
  etc..

with `print '<td>' .$row["klass"].'</td>';`
prints whole text. Can I print somehow until to "(" ?

to display :

- DS1
- DCK1
- DBW
- etc...

Comment: You mean for the first example it will display `DS1` ?

Comment: @ Abhik Chakraborty Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`preg_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove the entire paranthesis :

```
function removeParanthesis($text) {
    return preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $text);
}

print '<td>'.removeParanthesis($row["klass"]).'</td>';
```

Would give the desired output.

Comment: Thank's @davidkonrad this function example works for me like I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it mysql as

```
mysql> select substring_index('DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)','(',1) as klass ;
+-------+
| klass |
+-------+
| DS1   |
+-------+
```

So while selecting you may do as

```
select 
substring_index(klass,'(',1) as klass
from table_name
```

Comment: and in my case right now query is:
'$results4 = $mysqli->query("
  SELECT * FROM BC2014 WHERE klass = 'DR6 (4-6 koera karuvedu al. 16 a.)' ");'
How put substring in right way to query ?

Comment: if your `klass` are long strings then why you need them in the comarison ? unless its something as `substring_index(klass,'(',1) = 'DS1'`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the [explode() function](https://php.net/explode)

```
print '<td>' . explode("(", $row["klass"])[0] . '</td>';
```

Comment: Seems a little expensive.